# Does having more towers built on map affect loot quality?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Does having more towers built on map affect loot quality (negatively)? I followed [this guide](http://www.dadsgamingaddiction.com/dungeon-defenders-farming-level-74-mythical-gear/#comment-160502) to obtain my first mythical gear. The first time I succeeded I think I only had 4-5 critical towers placed on map and I got mythical gear from all 4 chests. Now that I'm stronger, I am able to build 9 critical towers by the end of the wave and I often get 0-1 mythical items.

Does this happen by pure chance or should I sell some towers just before the wave ends?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Dungeon Defenderd 1 and not Eternia. I was once told that having used all of your defense points improved the loot that was dropped. Unfortunately I don't have hard evidence of that, but if I find some I'll put it into an answer.

Comment: If you would like I could set you up with some gear, possibly even a full set. My steam name is: Moist Anticipation. Just fire me a pm :)

Comment: @slow_excellence done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the number of towers or Defense Units used does not affect loot quality in any way. The only thing tower count impacts is a small score bonus if you max out Defense Units, and having a ton of towers may impact frame rate (especially fireball towers).

RNG plays a huge impact in this game however; you may get a large streak of significant upgrades followed by a long drought of no upgrades. It is random though, but what defenses you use and/or how many of them you use does not affect it.